# Formally proving that a metric is not induced by any norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, elementary-proofs

What is the procedure to formally prove that no norm exists in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that induces a metric $d$?

My first instinctive idea would be to show that $d$ is a metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but after this I don't know any further. What could I achieve by following this road?

The specific problem I am working on is to prove that no norm $||\cdot||$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ exists, that induces the metric $d$:

$d((x_\text{1},y_\text{1}),(x_\text{2},y_\text{2})) :=
\begin{cases}
  |y_\text{1}-y_\text{2}|, & \text{if }x_\text{1} = x_\text{2},\\
  |y_\text{1}| + |x_\text{1}-x_\text{2}| + |y_\text{2}|, & \text{if }x_\text{1} \not= x_\text{2}.
\end{cases}$

I do not intend to get solutions for my specific problem, but maybe a similar problem exists elsewhere, which I could study. Of course, I have searched MathOverflow, and other sources.

Comment: A metric induced by a norm satisfies, for example $d(0,2x)=2d(0,x)$, $d(0,x)=d(0,-x)$, $d(x,y)=d(x+c,y+c)$ and many other things like this, which general metrics do not satisfy.

Answer (score 2):

$(0,2)$ and $(1,1)$ are at distance $2+1+1=4$.

$(1,1)$ and $(2,0)$ are at distance $1+1+0=2$.

But that's a contradiction, $(1,1)$ being the midpoint of $(0,2)-(2,0)$.